# PowerShell to delete files not matching an array of user names

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a simple database query that returns an array of current users
e.g.
ABB016
ACQ002
AGU003
AHM007

I would like to delete all files in a particular folder that have a name to the left of the file ending (BaseName) that can not be found within this array.

The code below is what I currently have, however at the moment it would delete all the files in this directory

```
# Find files that do not have the same basename as current users' name and delete
Get-ChildItem -path $DirectoryWithFiles -rec *.* | Where-Object {
      $SQLQeryResultsSet -NotContains $_.BaseName } | 
   Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "ABB016.pdf".

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "ACQ002.pdf".

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "AGU003.pdf".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe verify that `$SQLQeryResultsSet` in fact contains the expected string values. ie check `$SQLQeryResultsSet[0]` is the expected first username and `$SQLQeryResultsSet[0].GetType()` returns `String`

Comment: Thanks @Mathias $SQLQeryResultsSet[0] -> ABB016 and $SQLQeryResultsSet[0].GetType() -> DataRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your comments suggest, `$SQLQeryResultsSet` is not an array of strings, but a `DataTable`.

You could extract the individual string values from first column in each data row like this:

```
$ExcludedUsers = $SQLQeryResultsSet |ForEach-Object { '{0}' -f $_.Item(0) }
```

Then use this new variable in place of `$SQLQeryResultsSet` in the `Where-Object` filter scriptblock

Comment: Thanks @Mathias that worked perfectly - now working as expected and excluding current users $ExcludedUsers[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object